# I am trying to display detail list of may json response in UITableViewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Hi I am trying to display detail information of json data in second table view but their is some mistake in my logic so please help me my json response is in image and I am trying to to dispaly channel response in table view when user click the same cat_id then display all related channel list and image in second tableViewcell please help me..[image]

```
    -(void)getCategories
    {
        Service *srv=[[Service alloc]init];

        NSString *str=@"http://streamtvbox.com/site/api/matrix/";//?country_code=91&phone=9173140993&fingerprint=2222222222";
        NSString *method=@"channels";
        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


        [srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:dict completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)

         {
             NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[responseObj valueForKey:@"categories"]];

                      arrayChannelList=[responseObj valueForKey:@"channels"];
                      NSLog(@"Array : %@",channels);

                      for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayChannelList)
                      {
                          //NSArray *tempTitle = [[NSArray alloc]init];

                          arrayCat_Id = [dict objectForKey:@"cat_id"];

                      }

             tempArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
             tempArray = [dict allKeys];
             for(int i=0; i<tempArray.count; i++)
             {

                 [arrayCategories addObject:[dict valueForKey:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
             }
             NSLog(@"%@",arrayCategories);
             [tblView reloadData];

         }];
    }




    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[arrayCategories count]);
        return arrayCategories.count;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChannelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    DetailChannelsViewController *detailVC = (DetailChannelsViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];

    detailVC.channelTitle = [arrayCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailVC.SubChannelName = arrayCat_Id;

    NSLog(@"%@",arrayCat_Id);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];




}
```

Comment: arrayCat_Id is Nsmutuable Array?

Comment: Hi, yes are you their ?

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize of your NSmutuableArray and add the value of with addobject like:-

```
arrayCat_Id=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(your logic){
    [arrayCat_Id addobject:[dict objectForKey:@"cat_id"];
```

}